# Set replSet without restarting the mongod

Tags: mongodb, replication, mongohq

Is any way that I can assign the `replSet` without restarting the `mongod`? [MongoDB Doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) says that we should restart the mongo and assign some parameters, but I'm using MongoHQ's service (via Heroku), I can't find the way to set the `replSet`. How can I do it?

Comment: I assume you have a replica set at MongoHQ? Why not let them configure it according to your requirements? Isn't that why you're using a cloud solution in the first place? Their support is very good from my experience. Not sure if you can or should apply such changes yourself...

Comment: AFAIK you cannot change the command line options while the mongod is running